# How to catch failed Laravel 5.7 Mail "later" queue job exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue, jobs

I'm using: `Mail::later($when, $mailable);` ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#queueing-mail))

And I happened to notice in my `failed_jobs` table some entries saying that some queued mail failed because of missing views. ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs))

But it was just luck that I noticed it.

I *thought* what would happen if queued mail ever failed was that an Exception would be thrown, which would then notify my Slack app because of how I set up `App\Exceptions\Handler` and a custom logger in `config/logging.php`.

**How can I get `App\Exceptions\Handler` to properly report a failed call of `Mail::later()` or `Mail::queue()`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I figured it out

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#failed-job-events showed me that I could edit the `boot` function of `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` to have:

```
Queue::failing(function (JobFailed $event) {
    Log::error('JobFailed. ' . json_encode(['connectionName' => $event->connectionName, 'job' => $event->job, 'exception' => $event->exception])); 
});
```

To test whether this worked locally, I set `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync` in my local `.env` and then ran `php artisan queue:work --tries=1 --daemon > storage/logs/laravel.log`.

It successfully logged exceptions from `Mail::later`.

Note, however, that `laravel.log` didn't update immediately; there was a delay of about a minute.

Comment: Thanks for showing it. I already used `Queue::failing()` in `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`, but didn't think of `--daemon > storage/logs/laravel.log`. However this seems to work for internal laravel and php exception only. Misconfigured mailing seems to fail silently. I have forgotten to change my GMAIL config for `MAIL_HOST`, and `Queue::failing()` never caught it. So I wonder if `--daemon > storage/logs/laravel.log` could make any difference. I already have redis in Mac OSx,  I'll try it.

Answer (score -3):

You can use failed job tables which will have the listing of failed jobs.

Comment: The 2nd sentence of my question already says that the `failed_jobs` table was *how* I first happened to notice the failure. But I wanted to know a way to be alerted immediately.